# Recommended Syntax for Calling a Package's Own Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Say I have the Package below (please take note of the comments):

```
Create or replace package test_package_own_proc as

    procedure ext_proc1;
    procedure ext_proc2;
    procedure ext_proc3;

end test_package_own_proc;
/

Create or replace package body test_package_own_proc as

    procedure ext_proc1
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to StackOverflow');
        dbms_output.put_line('default procedure');

    end ext_proc1;

    procedure ext_proc2
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to Oracle Forums');
        dbms_output.put_line('i will call ext_proc1 without the package name');
        ext_proc1;   -- without package name

    end ext_proc2;

    procedure ext_proc3
    is
    begin

        dbms_output.put_line('Welcome to Some Website');
        dbms_output.put_line('i will call ext_proc1 with the package name');
        test_package_own_proc.ext_proc1;    -- with package name

    end ext_proc3;        

end test_package_own_proc;
```

What is the recommended Syntax to call procedure `ext_proc1`? Is it With or Without the Package Name?
In the same vein, are there any Advantage/Disadvantage in calling the Procedure With the Package Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to call procedures without suffixing package name.

Any local procedures (defined with in same package) should be called without referencing package name. By this convention it is easy to understand procedure is local. Also, this make future changes easy, in case if you wish to change package name, you will not have to change code written with in package body.

Answer (score 0):

Internal package proc will have precedence over the non-package public proc; so no matter how you call it inside the package, it's the package member that gets executed, with or without full specs.

Comment: Yes may be correct, but my question was, what is the Recommended Syntax?